# Ruby On Rails, code in each loop in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, each

I have a little problem...
My View:

```
  --html---
    <% @things each do |thing| %>
    <% other = @others.find_by(:ID == thing.ID)%>---->it runs just once. Why? 
      <div>    
        <p>thing.ID</p> --------------->  This is correct.
        <p>other.NAME</p> -------------> But it isn't. It is always same (fisrt value..).
      </div>
    <%end%>
  --html--
```

I like this, that the other.NAME changes too. Thanks for the help!

Comment: have you try `@others.find_by(:ID => thing.ID)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `==` when you need `=>`

`:ID == thing.ID` is evaluated to false, which leads to:

`@others.find_by(false)`  which happens to return the first record every time.

Also, your naming of attributes is not standard - by rails convention they should be small letters:  `other.name`

Answer (score 0):

you can used following query to find 'other'

```
other = @others.find_by_ID(thing.ID)
```

if record not found it will return 'nil' and not 'record not found' error.
You can used

```
other.try(:NAME)
```

other.name will give error if 'other = nil'.